# Julia adding indexed arrays

Tags: arrays, addition, julia

I have two arrays in Julia: `A`, which has size `(2,2,3)` and `a` which has size `(2,2)`.

If I try to perform the following operation

```
a += A[:,:,1]
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: LoadError: DimensionMismatch("dimensions must match")
in promote_shape at operators.jl:231
in promote_shape at operators.jl:227
in + at arraymath.jl:96
```

I looked at the array documentation and couldn't figure out how to get around this issue.

Comment: Are you sure? I tried with `Float64` arrays and it works both in `julia 0.4.5` and `julia 0.5.0-dev`. Can you give more information about these arrays?

Comment: I think perhaps an update was all I needed. Sorry!